# If I write tests for database calls then I'm writing unit tests or integration tests?

Tags: testing

I am starting to write tests for database calls and queries. But I was wondering, since it doesn't depend on any other function, then writing test for database calls are unit tests?

Edit: This is around a Node.js environment

Answer (score 0):

The database is *separate* to the application that you are testing, and as such, the tests would be ***integration*** tests rather than unit tests.

Note that unit tests are limited to dealing with single pieces of software in *isolation*. If you explicitly want to unit test your code as it stands (without making actual database calls), you can make use of a mocking framework, such as [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq).

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention. This is around a node.js environment! But I guess the use cases are similar. Didn't hear about mocking frameworks before, so I might need to understand this a little better. The first thing that comes to my mind is, by mocking database calls (in this case) they don't exactly execute, right?